# Use of Anonymous Inner Class in java

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

```
public SampleBehaviour otherway(final String st) {
    return new SampleBehaviour() {
        private String str = st;

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("val:"+val);
        }

    };
}
```

`SampleBehaviour` is an interface.

Classes that implements an interface must define the methods behavior, whats the use of some variables in interface?

Why does the method parameter need to be final? I don't get some real time application for this type of usage? What's the real thing behind this?

If it's useful, why doesn't C++ have something like this?

Comment: *if its useful,why we C++ doesn't have something like this?* because that's not how the language was designed.

Comment: Back to your question, anonymous classes aren't allowed to modify the  reference of the method parameters, so they must be marked as `final` in order to being used in the anonymous class.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why it should not modify?

Comment: That's the way how it is designed. Refer to [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing) and [JSL: 15.9.5. Anonymous Class Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)

Comment: In one line: This is because Java does not support lexical closures.

The language designers felt that introducing them would introduce more code-readability issues than produce gain.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), Section 8.1.3:

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

Wikipedia says that it's so the inner class needs to keep its own copy of the variable since it can live on after the outer class goes out of scope; to prevent having the same variable name refer to two different locations, they forced the variable to be fixed in place.